# Pandas Grouper Function using Key as "datetime"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe. The datetime field starts with `2019-01-28 09:15:00` and ends at `2019-01-28 15:29:00`

When I am using

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='30Min')])
```

it by default takes the first 30 Min datetime bracket as `*09:00:00 to 09:30:00*` where as I want `*09:15:00 to 09:45:00*`

Sample DataFrame:

```
             datetime      Close       Volume
57    2019-01-28 09:15:00  10788.00    4275
58    2019-01-28 09:15:00  10785.25    2025
59    2019-01-28 09:15:00  10788.00    1200
60    2019-01-28 09:16:00  10788.60    1125
61    2019-01-28 09:16:00  10787.00     450
117   2019-01-28 09:16:00  10781.10     450
118   2019-01-28 09:16:00  10780.90     450
119   2019-01-28 09:17:00  10781.05    9075
120   2019-01-28 09:17:00  10779.00     150
121   2019-01-28 09:17:00  10778.75     225
178   2019-01-28 09:18:00  10777.00     675
179   2019-01-28 09:18:00  10775.95     450
180   2019-01-28 09:18:00  10776.95     450
191   2019-01-28 09:18:00  10785.90    3600
...
15431 2019-01-28 15:29:00  10695.15     675
```

Comment: define `base = df.datetime.iloc[0].minute + df.datetime.iloc[0].second/60` and add it as an argument to the `Grouper`

Comment: Thanks. This "base = df.datetime.iloc[0].minute + df.datetime.iloc[0].second/60" is working.